# Show a set is in the null space of the transpose of A

Tags: linear-algebra

I'm trying to show that for $A \in F^{MxN}$ (a matrix with the nth column $a_n$) the following set is in the null space of $A^T$, that is:

$N(A^T) = \{x \in \Re^M : A^Tx = 0\} = \{x \in F^M : \sum\limits_{m=1}^M a_n(m)x(m) = 0 : \forall n = 1,...,N\}$

where $A^T \in F^{NxM}, (A^T)(n,m) := A(m,n)$

This seems intuitive, since the null space is the set of all vectors where $Ax=0$, however how can I prove mathematically that its in the null space of $A^T$?  Thank you in advance!

Answer (score 1):

Using the given notation we have
$$A=(a_1\;\ldots\;a_N)$$
hence
$$A^T=(a^T_1\;\ldots\;a^T_N)$$
so $$x=(x(1),\ldots,x(M))^T\in N(A^T)\iff A^Tx=0\iff (a^T_1\;\ldots\;a^T_N)x=0\\\iff (a^T_1x\;\ldots\;a^T_Nx)=0\iff\langle a_n,x\rangle=0,\;\forall n=1,\ldots,N\\\iff\sum_{m=1}^M a_n(m)x(m)=0,\;\forall n=1,\ldots,N $$